# Identificando os campos corretos de acordo com o Select para preencher os dados nos indexes corretos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Bom dia pessoal, estou com um problema onde já fiz algo parecido em outras funções do meu sistema mas nessa em específico não está funcionando. Tenho uma função que adiciona e remove DIVs de produtos em meu sistema e nestas contem um SELECT que trás os nomes dos Produtos, quando o produto é escolhido é populado também seu Código, sua Embalagem e a quantidade de sua Embalagem. O problema está sendo que cada SELECT ao ser escolhido deve popular os dados em sua DIV e está ocorrendo que está populando em todas dos outros produtos. Como posso percorrer e apenas popular nos campos corretos ?

principal.php // Estrutura da DIV Produtos:

```
 <div class="container" id="produtos">
                        <div class="separator"></div>

                        <div class="title-padrao">
                            <h1 class="text-center">
                                Produtos
                            </h1>
                        </div>

                        <div id="allProducts">
                            <section id="all-section">

                                <div class="inform-produtos">

                                    <div class="primeira">
                                        <b>Item:</b>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="segunda">
                                        <b>Cod.:</b>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="terceira">
                                        <b>Selecione um produto:</b>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="quantidade-embalagem">
                                        <b>Qtd. Embalagem:</b>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="quarta">
                                        <b>Embalagem:</b>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="quinta">
                                        <b>Preço:</b>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="sexta">
                                        <b>Quantidade:</b>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="setima">
                                        <b>Preço Produto:</b>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clone-prod" name="clone-prod[]">

                                    <div class="wrap-prod" name="wrap-prod[]">

                                        <div class="produtos-wrap" name="produtos-wrap[]">
                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="primeiro-produto">
                                                <input type="text" class="index font-pop input-div" id="index_produto"
                                                    name="index_produto[]" value="1" readonly="true" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="segundo-produto">
                                                <input class="font-pop number_id_produto input-div" value=""
                                                    readonly="true" name="id_produto[]" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao terceiro-produto"
                                                id="terceiro-produto" name="terceiro-produto[]">
                                                <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="false"
                                                    data-live-search="true" name="select_produtos[]"
                                                    id="select_produtos" onchange="initProdutos(this)" required>
                                                    <?php
                                                    echo '<option disabled selected hidden
                                                    value="Selecione um produto..."
                                                    data-subtext="Selecione um produto...">Selecione um produto...
                                                    </option>';
                                                    foreach ($res as $item_produtos) {
                                                        echo '<option data-subtext="' . $item_produtos['CODACESSO'] . '" value="'
                                                        . $item_produtos['CODACESSO'] . "|" . $item_produtos['EMBALAGEM'] . "|" 
                                                        . $item_produtos['QTDEMBALAGEM'] . '">' . $item_produtos['DESCCOMPLETA'] . '</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="quantidade-embalagem">
                                                <input type="text" class="edit-input font-pop"
                                                    name="qtdembalagem[]" value="" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="quarto-produto">
                                                <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="edit-input font-pop"
                                                    name="embalagem[]" value="" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="quinto-produto">
                                                <input type="number" id="preco-input" name="preco[]" step="0.01" min="0"
                                                    class="edit-input font-pop" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="sexto-produto">
                                                <input type="number" id="qtd-input" step="0.01" min="0"
                                                    class="edit-input font-pop" value="" name="quantidade-produto[]"
                                                    required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao" id="setimo-produto">
                                                <input class="font-pop preco-produto input-div" readonly="true"
                                                    name="preco-produto[]" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="text-center select_height produto-padrao oitavo-produto"
                                            id="div-remove">
                                            <button type="button"
                                                class="remover glyphicon glyphicon-remove button-produto"></button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </section>
                            <div id="wrap-addbutton">
                                <button type="button" id="add-button"
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign button-produto"></button>
                                <b>Adicione um produto...</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Function que adiciona / remove Produtos:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clone = $(".clone-prod").html();
    $(document).on('click', '#add-button', addProd);

    $(document).on('click', '.remover', function () {
        if ($('.wrap-prod').length === 1) {
            $('.remover').attr('disabled', true);
            alert('Não é possivel remover o único produto do Pedido !');
        } else {
            $(this).parents('.wrap-prod').remove();
            ids();
            calculos();
        }
    });

    function addProd() {
        $('.clone-prod').append(clone);
        ids();
        $('.clone-prod .selectpicker').selectpicker();
        $('.remover').attr('disabled', false);
    }

    function ids() {
        $("[name='index_produto[]']").each(function (i, e) {
            $(e).val(i + 1);
        });
    }
})
```

Function que capturo o valor / populo os dados do Produto:

```
var prod = [];
function initProdutos(e) {
    var wraper = $(e).closest(".produtos-wrap"); // pega a div principal
    var letras_produtos = $("[name='select_produtos[]']", wraper).val();

    const $preco = $("[name='preco[]']", wraper);
    const $qtd = $("[name='quantidade-produto[]']", wraper);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "API.php",
        data: {
            "mode": "produtos",
            "letras_produtos": letras_produtos
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        //CASO DÊ TUDO CERTO
        success: function (data) {
            prod = [];
            var len = data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                prod.push(data[i]['CODACESSO'] + "|" + data[i]['EMBALAGEM'] + "|" + data[i]['QTDEMBALAGEM']);
            }
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            //console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
    $preco.on('input', recalculate());
    $qtd.on('input', recalculate());
}


$(document).on("change", "[name='select_produtos[]']", function () {
    setValue(this.value);
});


function setValue(valor) {
    var tmp = valor.split("|");
    var wraper = $("[name='select_produtos[]']").closest(".produtos-wrap");

    $('[name="id_produto[]"]', wraper).val(tmp[0]);
    $('[name="embalagem[]"]', wraper).val(tmp[1]);
    $('[name="qtdembalagem[]"]', wraper).val(tmp[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema, apenas alterei a seguinte function:

```
$(document).on("change", "select", "[name='select_produtos[]']", function () {
    var wraper = $(this).closest(".produtos-wrap");
    setValue(this.value);


    function setValue(valor) {
        var tmp = valor.split("|");

        $('[name="id_produto[]"]', wraper).val(tmp[0]);
        $('[name="embalagem[]"]', wraper).val(tmp[1]);
        $('[name="qtdembalagem[]"]', wraper).val(tmp[2]);
    }
});
```